# No encuentro el error en mi programa pero cada que lo inicio se congela, dice esto 'Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.StackOverflowException'.'

Tags: c#

-Esta es la clase y lo estoy haciendo en visual studio y no me marca error, alguien podria ayudarme con el codigo por favor es urgente es mi proyecto final.
Este es el programa Principal:

```
            Estimulos e = new Estimulos();

            Console.WriteLine("Estimulo de boletos estudiante vendidos --->: 
            ");
            e.Boletoes = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Estimulo de boletos tercera edad vendidos --->: " );
            e.Boletote = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Estimulo de boletos generales --->: " );
            e.Boletog = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Cantidad ganada de los boletos:$ " + e.Estimulo());
            Console.WriteLine("Importe total de los boletos de hoy: " + e.Importet());
            Console.WriteLine("Su sueldo de hoy es:$ " + e.Sueldo());
            Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Esta es la clase
class Estimulos
{
private int boletoes;
private int boletog;
private int boletote;

```
    public Estimulos()
    {

    }

    public int Boletoes
    {
        get { return boletoes; }
        set { boletoes = value; }
    }
    public int Boletog
    {
        get { return boletog; }
        set { boletog = value; }
    }
    public int Boletote
    {
        get { return boletote; }
        set { boletote = value; }
    }

    public int Importebe()
    {
        int cantidad = 0;
        cantidad = boletoes * 10;
        return cantidad;
    }
    public int Importebg()
    {
        int cantidad = 0;
        cantidad = Boletog * 18;
        return cantidad;
    }
    public int Importebte()
    {
        int cantidad = 0;
        cantidad = boletote * 5;
        return cantidad;
    }

    public double Estimulo()
    {
        double total = 0;
        double est;
        total = Importebe() + Importebg() + Importebte();
        est = total * 0.25;
        return Estimulo();
    }

    public double Importet()
    {
        double imptotal;

       imptotal = boletoes + boletog + boletote;
       return Importet();
    }

    public double Sueldo()
    {
        double total = 0;
        double totales;
        double totalter;
        double pago;
        if (total >= 1500)
        {

          totales = Importebe() * 0.10;
          totalter = Importebte() * 0.5;
          pago = totales + totalter;
            return pago;
        }
        
     }
```

Aqui abajo les dejo el problema que necesito resolver:

> Una empresa que tiene peseros, le da estímulos a sus choferes de acuerdo a la cantidad de dinero que hayan reunido durante el día. A los estudiantes se les cobra $10, a los adultos de la tercera edad $5 y a las demás personas $18. A cada chofer se le paga el 25% del total conseguido en un día. Cuando el chofer ha conseguido reunir más de $1500 en un día, se le da un estímulo del 10% de lo que se consiguió por el pasaje de los estudiantes, de lo contrario el estímulo es el 5% del pasaje total de los adultos de la tercera edad.
> Crear una clase que contenga lo siguiente:
> ·         Atributos: cantidad de boletos de estudiantes, cantidad de boletos de adultos de la tercera edad y cantidad de boletos normales
> ·         Descriptores de acceso
> ·         Un método que devuelva el importe de los boletos de los estudiantes
> ·         Un método que devuelva el importe de los boletos de los adultos mayores
> ·         Un método que devuelva el importe de los boletos normales
> ·         Un método que devuelva la cantidad de estímulo que se gana el chofer
> ·         Un método que devuelva el importe total de todos los boletos
> ·         Un método que devuelva el sueldo total de chofer
> Crear un programa que utilice un objeto de la clase anterior y muestre la información que proporcionan sus métodos.

Comment: Por qué estás devolviendo el método? `return Estimulo(); return Importe(); return Sueldo();`. Será esto lo que está causando la recursión y luego el StackOverflow? Intenta `return cantidad;`

Comment: Esa es solo la clase y necesito que en el programa principal me muestre el resultado de eso, no se si necesito usar un while

Comment: ya lo hice y si funciona hasta la mitad y ya no me marca lo demas que necesito solo los importes de los boletos, despues se congela y sale de nuevo el stackOverflow

Comment: No veo como el while te va a resolver la `StackOverflowException`. Por qué estás devolviendo los métodos en lugar de `cantidad`? Ya leíste qué significa StackOverflowException? Siempre es bueno leer la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=net-5.0#remarks): *StackOverflowException is thrown for execution stack overflow errors, typically in case of a **very deep or unbounded recursion**. So make sure your code doesn't have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.* Estás devolviendo un método que devuelve un método que devuelve un metodo

Comment: ya puse lo de cantidad pero como te digo sigue marcando error a la mitad del programa , es que soy nuevo haciendo programas y queria ayuda con mi tarea porque es mi proyecto final.

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu código. Todavía parece que Cuando llamas a `Importet()`, este devuelve `Importet()` que llama `Importet()` que devuelve `Importet()` que llama `Importet()` que `devuelve Importet()` que llama `Importet()` que devuelve `Importet()`. Cuando llamas `Importebg()` devuelve  `Importebg()` que llama  `Importebg()` que devuelve  `Importebg()` que llama  `Importebg()` que devuelve  `Importebg()` que llama  `Importebg()` que devuelve  `Importebg()`....

Comment: Ya lo actualice

Comment: `Importet()`, `Estimulo()` también están devolviendo métodos, en lugar de `double`. Has intentado depurar el código?

Comment: Este codigo, no compila.. por ejemplo el metodo Sueldo no devuelve nada en una de las rutas, y entonces daria error. que queres devolver cuando haces return Importet();
???? supongo que en esos metodos, queres devolver lo que calculaste internametne, entonces ahi iria la variable a devolver, no?

Answer (score 0):

En los dos metodos siguientes estas haciendo una llamada recursiva al propio metodo, eso provoca el error de desbordamiento de pila o `StackOverflowException`, pues el compilador se quedaria llamando al propio metodo de manera indefinida.

```
  public double Estimulo()
    {
        double total = 0;
        double est;
        total = Importebe() + Importebg() + Importebte();
        est = total * 0.25;
        //La siguiente es una llamada recursiva al propio metodo
        return Estimulo(); 
        //Sutituye la linea anterior por la siguiente
        return  est;
    }

    public double Importet()
    {
        double imptotal;

       imptotal = boletoes + boletog + boletote;
       //La siguiente es una llamada recursiva al propio metodo
       return Importet();
        //Sutituye la linea anterior por la siguiente
        return  imptotal;
    }
```